# How to enable the DMP of the MPU9250?

Tags: sampling, register, motion

The datasheet mentions some `Advanced Hardware Features` which gets executed by the Digital Motion Processor. I'd like to use the `Android Orientation` motion-based function and send the orientation with SPI to the microcontroller. However I can't seem to find the registers in the MPU9250 I need to enable this. I've looked through both the [datasheet](http://43zrtwysvxb2gf29r5o0athu-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf) and [register map](http://43zrtwysvxb2gf29r5o0athu-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/RM-MPU-9250A-00-v1.6.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Advanced Hardware Features on Page 54 of the Register Map document it says, *"For further details **please see the Application Note** 'Programming Sequence for DMP Hardware Functions."'*

In that app note on page 23:

[image]

as well as a ton of related stuff after it.

https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU9250/blob/master/Documents/Application%20Note%20-%20Programming%20Sequence%20for%20DMP%20Hardware%20Functions%20v12%20(....pdf

**EDIT:** Someone goofed and removed the sentence from Register Map document v1.6. It is in v1.4. That is why you were lost. You were looking at v1.6.

Comment: Huh, what version is that Register Map document? I have V1.6 open and there is no `6.1` and `6.2`, only `6`

Comment: @Swedgin It's not in the register map document. It's in the app note that the Register Map document refers to.

Comment: @Swedgin Someone goofed and removed the sentence from  Register Map document v1.6. It is in v1.4

Comment: Ok will look for the 1.4 version. I was losing my brain when not being able to locate these 2 sections haha.

Comment: Found a link https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU9250/blob/master/Documents/Application%20Note%20-%20Programming%20Sequence%20for%20DMP%20Hardware%20Functions%20v12%20(....pdf

Comment: @Swedgin I don't know why the only copy is hosted on github and not their official company site

Comment: me neither, but I'm glad I found it. Thanks for your help